# can't save my ArrayList on a Button's click

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save, sharedpreferences

this is a simple app who needs to get locations,add/remove them from an arraylist and save the list on a click button,using Sharedpreferences and not other storing methods.
for some reason it just won't save anything.
here's my code:

```
    package com.example.pearls1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public int ItemCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locListener);

        Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        Button buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);
        SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                "myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (int Counter=0; Counter< sharedPreferences.getInt("Count", 0); Counter++)
        {
            list.add(sharedPreferences.getString("Item" + Integer.toString(Counter), ""));
        }

        OnClickListener listenerAdd = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PearlNumber);
                EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
                EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);

                list.add("Pearl Number:" + edit.getText().toString() + "   X:"
                        + edit1.getText().toString() + "   Y:"
                        + edit2.getText().toString());
                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SaveItem(edit.getText().toString(), edit1.getText().toString(),
                        edit2.getText().toString());
            };

        };

        OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView()
                        .getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

        OnClickListener listenerSave = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);
                SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                        "myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("Count", list.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < ItemCounter; i++) {
                    editor.putString("Item" + Integer.toString(i), list.get(i));
                }
                editor.commit();
            }

        };

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(listenerAdd);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(listenerSave);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void SaveItem(String pearl, String Anumber, String Bnumber) {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);

        ItemCounter++;

        /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("pearl" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)), pearl);
        editor.putString("Anumber" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)),
                Anumber);
        editor.putString("Bnumber" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)),
                Bnumber);

        // Storing the count of Item count
        editor.putInt("ItemCounter", ItemCounter);
        /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
        editor.commit();

    }
package com.example.pearls1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public int ItemCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locListener);

        Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        Button buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);
        SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                "myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (int Counter=0; Counter< sharedPreferences.getInt("Count", 0); Counter++)
        {
            list.add(sharedPreferences.getString("Item" + Integer.toString(Counter), ""));
        }

        OnClickListener listenerAdd = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PearlNumber);
                EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
                EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);

                list.add("Pearl Number:" + edit.getText().toString() + "   X:"
                        + edit1.getText().toString() + "   Y:"
                        + edit2.getText().toString());
                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SaveItem(edit.getText().toString(), edit1.getText().toString(),
                        edit2.getText().toString());
            };

        };

        OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView()
                        .getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

        OnClickListener listenerSave = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);
                SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                        "myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("Count", list.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < ItemCounter; i++) {
                    editor.putString("Item" + Integer.toString(i), list.get(i));
                }
                editor.commit();
            }

        };

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(listenerAdd);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(listenerSave);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void SaveItem(String pearl, String Anumber, String Bnumber) {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SaveListItem", 0);

        ItemCounter++;

        /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("pearl" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)), pearl);
        editor.putString("Anumber" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)),
                Anumber);
        editor.putString("Bnumber" + Integer.toString((ItemCounter - 1)),
                Bnumber);

        // Storing the count of Item count
        editor.putInt("ItemCounter", ItemCounter);
        /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
        editor.commit();

    }
```

Comment: I assume it's only saving the last item?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to cut down your code to just what someone would need to see where the problem is? Multiple files of code can be difficult to parse and find issues in.

Comment: it doesn't save anything.
I don't have any Error,it shows me the items added and once I reopen the app nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that will display saved items.. i stripped some of the irrelevant things. Anyway you were saving count using 2 strings "itemCount" and "count". Try to do something like this:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

  private static final String SAVE_LIST_ITEM = "SaveListItem";
  private static final String COUNT = "Count";
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  public int itemCounter = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
Button buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

// Opening the sharedPreferences object
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_LIST_ITEM, MODE_PRIVATE);
itemCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt(COUNT, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < itemCounter; i++) {
  list.add(sharedPreferences.getString("Item" + Integer.toString(i), ""));
}

buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PearlNumber);
    EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
    EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);

    list.add("Pearl Number:" + edit.getText().toString() + "   X:"
        + edit1.getText().toString() + "   Y:"
        + edit2.getText().toString());
    // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    saveItem(edit.getText().toString(), edit1.getText().toString(),
        edit2.getText().toString());
  }
});

buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView()
        .getCheckedItemPositions();
    int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

    for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
      }
    }
    checkedItemPositions.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});

buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNT, list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCounter; i++) {
      editor.putString("Item" + Integer.toString(i), list.get(i));
    }
    editor.commit();
  }
});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}

private void saveItem(String pearl, String Anumber, String Bnumber) {
    itemCounter++;

```
/** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("pearl" + Integer.toString((itemCounter - 1)), pearl);
editor.putString("Anumber" + Integer.toString((itemCounter - 1)),
    Anumber);
editor.putString("Bnumber" + Integer.toString((itemCounter - 1)),
    Bnumber);

// Storing the count of Item count
editor.putInt(COUNT, itemCounter);
/** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
editor.commit();
```

}
}

Comment: thanks,but it still doesn't save me the item I deleted.